# How to call ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.encode(types, values) in python?

Tags: ethers.js, python, signature

I want to create a signature based on a hash value and a wallet address.
In nodejs I would do it like follows:

```
        const types = ["address", "bytes32"];

        const values = [address, hash];
        const message = ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.encode(types, values);
        const hash = ethers.utils.keccak256(message);

        const sig = await wallet.signMessage(ethers.utils.arrayify(hash));
```

But how do I do this in python?
I tried using the eth_abi module but it does not return the same message, hash or signature.

```
        types = ["address", "bytes32"]
        values = [address, codecs.decode(hash, 'hex')]
        encoded_message = encode_packed(types, values)
        hash_message = Web3.keccak(encoded_message)

        signed_message = account.signHash(hash_message)
        signature = signed_message['signature'].hex()
```

How can I mimic the process in nodejs in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from web3 import Web3
from eth_account import Account
from eth_abi import encode_abi_packed
import codecs

types = ["address", "bytes32"]
values = [address, codecs.decode(hash, 'hex')]
encoded_message = encode_abi_packed(types, values)
hash_message = Web3.keccak(encoded_message)

signed_message = Account.signHash(hash_message, private_key=private_key)
signature = signed_message['signature'].hex()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to verify the ethers output, but the correct way to encode with `eth_abi` is:

```py
from eth_abi import encode

types = ["address", "bytes32"]
values = [my_address, my_hash]
message = encode(types, values)
```

`my_hash` does need to be a python bytes object

If `message` here is different from `message` in the ethers example, there may well be a bug somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
from ethers import utils

types = ["address", "bytes32"]

values = [address, hash]
message = utils.defaultAbiCoder.encode(types, values)
hash = utils.keccak256(message)

sig = await wallet.signMessage(utils.arrayify(hash))
```